# Can i build solutions for SharePoint Foundation and SharePoint Server on the same development machine?

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation

My question is regarding the different SharePoint 2010 editions. Say I am running SharePoint Server on my development machine, since most of my solutions are made for SharePoint Server. If I should build a solution for SharePoint Foundation, I would like to configure my development machine so it does not let me do anything that would not work on SharePoint Foundation.

For example:

- the GUI should not show the SharePoint Server-specific site templates.
- if I by accident would set the property 'CustomMasterUrl', then when viewing the page I want it to behave as if I was using SharePoint Foundation.

Of course, without having to uninstall / reinstall anything.

Cheers,
Andreas

Answer (score 1):

You can use SharePoint Server 2010 with not activated server features such as publishing and so on. Just create a team site or a blank site. Also you need to create addition service application association to contain only services available for Foundation (without user profiles and so on).

Of course Server template, features and dll will be available, but you can avoid their usage.

Answer (score 1):

Andreas,

Your development environment should reflect the target environment as closely as possible to avoid problems during deployment. As such, I highly recommend that you have separate environments so that you can test your solutions locally and know they will work in production.

With the ease of access to virtual machines, there really isn't any reason to not have multiple environments. Using VMWare Player, Hyper-V, or VirtualBox, you can get away without paying extra for the virtualization environment. Add a TechNet or MSDN subscription and you have licenses to all the software you need for multiple environments.

If you don't have or don't want a local environment, you can even build one using Amazon's EC2 or similar services and just pay for your usage rather than licensing the software you need separately.

If you are experienced and know which features are available in each version (and don't forget, there are at least two versions of the Server version), then technically you can do development for both platforms using just one machine. However, because you ask this question, I'm assuming you don't have that level of confidence yet, so I would thus recommend separate environments.

.b

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually work these days is to use virtual machines. One VM setup for SharePoint Foundation dev, and another for SharePoint Server dev. That way you can have both environments ready to go whenever you need them without having to worry about this